# xcodebuild to notarize mac app and wait for response?

Tags: xcode10, notarize

I heavily rely on `xcodebuild` to automate the build process. Developers can now notarize their mac Developer ID apps before distribution, in Xcode 10.

I realize notarisation is an asynchronous process, one which involves waiting for Apple to 'review' and approve the app. In practice this seems to take less than 5 to 10 minutes.

Has anyone been able to automate this using the command line so we don't have to touch or use the Xcode Archiver Window? I cannot find a way. There seems to only be a `-exportNotarizedApp` option, which presumably only works if you already have the app notarised. No way to request notarization using the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An asynchronous notarization process can be automated using a new tool from Xcode toolchain named `altool`. You can read its documentation by running `xcrun altool` in the Terminal.

*P. S. I wrote a [blog post](https://nativeconnect.app/blog/mac-app-notarization-from-the-command-line/) with a working script, if this helps.*